# How to remove the player if any movement keys are being pressed in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a rhythm game in which the player block incoming attack with their back. To do this I've created a defend animation for each blocking direction. The idea is to activate the sprite renderer for the corresponding movement key, and deactivate the idle position. For whatever reason though, the  following code is stuck on saying that no keys are being pressed:

```
    public void positionDefault()
    {
        if (keyIsBeingPressed == false)
        {
            // Show the default sprite if no movement key is being pressed
            abbyDefaultPosition.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("no key is being pressed!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Hide the default sprite if any movement key is being pressed
            abbyDefaultPosition.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("a key is being pressed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the boolean keyIsBeingPressed:

```
keyIsBeingPressed = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow));
```

I have tried making the boolean using only one |.

I have also tried making the boolean a != statement.

Dank je van jij hulp!

Comment: You should flip the statement to :
`
if (keyIsBeingPressed) { //hide sprite }
else { //show sprite }
`
makes it a bit more readable

Comment: It would be a lot easier if we could see the full script. I take it the keyIsBeingPressed check is running in your Update function, and the positionDefault function is also being called from there. And you are still receiving "no key is being pressed"? -- I would say edit you question to include more of the script so we can see where the bool check is happening and where the function is being called from/how often. Since as it stands, everything here should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I simply put the Boolean in the Start function rather than the Update function.